# Another Yin Yang puzzle! Part two

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

I am sure this puzzle has only one solution. Also the solver of this puzzle can put up a Yin Yang puzzle if they wish to start a series.

Rules of Yin-Yang:

- Fill each empty cell with either a black circle or a white circle.
- All white circles should be orthogonally connected, so should all black circles.
- There may not be any 2x2 cell region consisting of the same circle color.

[image]

Comment: Why would you try to require any solver to make their own puzzle? That's both unenforceable and bad form - some people just want to solve puzzles, not create them.

Comment: Sorry I am trying to start a grid deduction series where solvers can post their own puzzles.

Comment: You could try organizing a series in the [main site chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair), but we already have a puzzle-series thing going on - [Chain Puzzles](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7018/chain-puzzle-within-scope-for-pse), which has its own [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115326/chain-puzzles) for organizing.

Comment: If people want to write their own puzzles, they can; some logic puzzle genres catch on. (Tapa and Nurikabe have both caught on around here in the past!) There's no need to *require* that someone else put one up.

Comment: Sorry I did not phrase that rightly. I have changed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two important facts that make Yin-Yang puzzles significantly easier:

> The **Checkerboard Rule**: No 2×2 square can be a checkerboard pattern.
>  And the **Border Rule**: The border of the puzzle must contain only one 'section' of each color; that is, the border changes color at most twice.

To start:

> The black dot on the left has to escape left. Use the Border Rule to get most of the border filled out:
>  [image]

Some connectivity, and application of both the "no 2×2" rule and "Checkerboard Rule" gets us here:

> [image]

More of the same:

> [image]

And applying those rules again finishes off the puzzle:

> [image]

Comment: May I know how to get those rules? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @00xxqhxx00 If you break either of those rules, you can't connect both white and black to each other: If there are two separate white sections on the edge, and you draw a line between them, then one black section is on the left and another is one the right. The same goes for a checkerboard pattern; no matter how you connect the whites, one black will be "inside" the loop formed
 and the other will be outside.